# Dificuldades no Envio de E-mail usando PHP

Tags: php, email, smtp

Com base no código abaixo, usado para envio de e-mail:

```
<?php
    $from     =  $_POST['email'];
    $to       = 'meuemail@gmail.com';
    $subject  =  $_POST['subject'];
    $message  =  $_POST['content'];
    $headers  = 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n" .
            'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
            'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8';
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
       echo "Email sent";
    else
       echo "Email sending failed";
?>
```

E o formulário:

```html
<form action="/mail/send-mail.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="contact-name" placeholder="Nome">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="contact-email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="contact-subject" placeholder="Assunto">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <textarea class="form-control" name="content" id="contact-content" placeholder="Mensagem" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default text-uppercase" id="contactButton"> Enviar</button>
 </form>
```

O retorno é sempre false.

Comment: está usando algum framework?

Comment: não estou......

Comment: O log do PHP diz alguma coisa?

Comment: porque a action do seu form está  assim `action="@routes.Assets.at("send-mail.php")"`?

Comment: `send-mail.php` é o nome do seu arquivo que vai realizar o envio do php?

Comment: Editato. Sim Erlon Charles!

Comment: Igor, você usa windows? Caso sim, para usar a função `mail`, você precisa de um serviço SMTP instalado. Recomendo que use PHPMailer para envio de e-mails. Já vem com suporte smtp, sem precisar instalar qualquer serviço. (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: Nada Vinícius! Só return false;

Comment: Rafael, uso Mac OS.

Comment: Dá uma olhadinha nesse artigo então: http://jasper.tandy.is/blogging/php-mail-and-osx-leopard/

Comment: Bom dia, gostaria de saber se alguma das respostas lhe ajudou, se não por favor comente o que acha que falta.

Answer (score 3):

Se sempre aparece a mensagem `Email sending failed` e o `false` ao qual você se refere é da função `mail`, então o motivo é a configuração do teu servidor.

Note que se estiver tentando usar isto em `http://localhost` e não um servidor real a função `mail` não irá funcionar e irá realmente sempre retornar `false`, se estiver tentando configurar seu próprio servidor será necessário configurar o SMTP no php.ini:

- **Windows**

  Se for Windows será necessário um aplicativo chamado `sendmail` que geralmente já vem instalado com o linux (no Windows o `sendmail` vem com o pacote do Xampp (Wamp/zwamp/easyphp não possui tal software no pacote)

  - Procure e edite o `sendmail.ini` (geralmente no Xampp para windows `C:\xampp\sendmail`):

    ```
    [sendmail]
    smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
    smtp_port = 587
    default_domain = gmail.com

    auth_username=[seuemail]@gmail.com
    auth_password=[suasenha]
    ```
  - Edite o `php.ini`:

    ```
    [mail function]
    sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"
    SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
    smtp_port = 587
    ```
- **Mac OSX**

  No Mac OSX Yosemite acredito ser algo como (conforme está resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26651732/1518921)):

  ```
  [mail function]
  sendmail_path = "env -i /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"
  SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
  smtp_port = 587
  ```
- **Configurando o Gmail**

  Para usar o Gmail basta acessar o link https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps e para liberar o acesso selecione **Ativo** aonde está escrito *Acesso para aplicativos menos seguros*.

  [Para mais detalhes do Gmail siga as instruções neste link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=pt-BR).

### Alternativa

Como alternativa você pode usar o [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) (deve-se liberar o acesso como descrito acima), exemplo:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Para outros problemas com o PHPMailer leia o link [PHPMailer/wiki](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting)

Comment: já editei meu php.ini, mas não obtive sucesso. como faço para usar esse PHPMailer?

Comment: instalei conforme suas orientações, mas agora após clicar no botão send a requisição torna-se interminável.

Comment: ¡2015-06-02 15:07:22 Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ( ) 2015-06-02 15:11:36 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable (101) 2015-06-02 15:11:36 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Li, parei no Gmail, OAuth2 and "Allow less secure apps, pois não encontrei o arquivo get_auth_token.php. que pede no link https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2. Os outros testes anteriores estão ok

Comment: Corrigigoo erros anteriores. Agora tenho 
SSL loaded 2015-06-02 17:53:28 Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

Comment: de qual script?

Comment: eu estava chamando a função sendmail, mas já removi. Agora voltou o erro 2015-06-02 15:07:22 Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ( ) 2015-06-02 15:11:36 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable (101) 2015-06-02 15:11:36 SMTP connect() failed. github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24389/discussion-between-guilherme-nascimento-and-igor-ronner).

Answer (score 2):

Sempre que preciso eu envio com PHPMailer !

**PHPMailer 2.3** : [Link para a class](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/phpmailer-2.3.0-msg-limit-patch/class.phpmailer.php)

```
<?php

require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");


$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Username = 'seuemail@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'sua_senha';

$mail->From = "remetente@mail.com";
$mail->Sender = "remetente@mail.com";
$mail->FromName = "Nome do remetente";

$mail->AddAddress('destinatario@mail.com', 'Assunto da mensagem');

//$mail->AddCC('emailpara@copia.com', 'Aqui o nome');
//$mail->AddBCC('emailcomcopia@oculta', 'Aqui o nome');

$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

$mail->Subject = "Assunto da Mensagem"; // Assunto da mensagem
$mail->Body = "Mensagem";


// Anexos
//$mail->AddAttachment("caminho/para/arquivo.pdf", "novo_nome.pdf");

$enviado = $mail->Send();

$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();

if ($enviado) {
    echo "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
} else {
    echo "Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.";
    echo "Informações do erro:" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu utilizo frameworks. Os mesmos costumam ter mecanismos próprios que não utilizam a função mail do PHP.

O problema da função mail do php é que você tem que mexer num arquivo de configuração. Tenho preferências sempre por utilizar bibliotecas que utilizam o SMTP.

Por exemplo, é o caso da [`Nette\Email`](https://packagist.org/packages/nette/mail).

De maneira bem simples, você pode enviar um e-mail.

```
use Nette\Mail\Message;
use Nette\Mail\SmtpMailer;

$mail = new Message;
$mail->setFrom('John <john@example.com>')
    ->addTo('peter@example.com')
    ->addTo('jack@example.com')
    ->setSubject('Order Confirmation')
    ->setHTMLBody("<b>Hello</b>, Your order has been accepted.");


$mailer = new SmtpMailer(array(
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'username' => 'john@gmail.com',
        'password' => '*****',
        'secure' => 'ssl',
));
$mailer->send($mail);
```

Essa biblioteca pode ser instalada facilmente via composer.

`composer require nette/mail`

Comment: +1 por não usar a função `mail()` outras desvantagens é montar certos cabeçalhos(email com anexo) na mão e passar certos argumentos/configurações para servidores de email especificos(postfix, qmail etc).

Comment: Nesse caso, realmente prefiro usar uma biblioteca específica. Toda vez que precisa enviar um e-mail com configurações diferentes, tem que trocar o tal do sendmail.ini.

Comment: [Exemplo de como mail é simples](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/74434/91) :P

Comment: @rray a concatenação cheira mal.