# Função mail() autenticado com anexo

Tags: php, formulário

Não posso usar a casse PHPMAILER, pois o servidor de hospedagem não aceita, (Informação do próprio suporte do servidor)

Tenho este exemplo, mas o arquivo em anexo, vem sempre com erro. e também não consigo escrever mensagem no corpo do email.

```
$boundary = "XYZ-".md5(date("dmYis"))."-ZYX";
$path = $_FILES['fTxtArquivo']['tmp_name']; 
$fileType = $_FILES['fTxtArquivo']['type']; 
$fileName = $_FILES['fTxtArquivo']['name']; 

// Pegando o conteúdo do arquivo
$fp = fopen( $path, "rb" ); // abre o arquivo enviado
$anexo = fread( $fp, filesize( $path ) ); // calcula o tamanho
$anexo = chunk_split(base64_encode( $anexo )); // codifica o anexo em base 64
fclose( $fp ); // fecha o arquivo

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ";
$headers .= "boundary=" . $boundary . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "$boundary" . PHP_EOL;

$mensagem  = "--$boundary" . PHP_EOL;
$mensagem .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset='utf-8'" . PHP_EOL;
$mensagem .= "Mensagem: teste"; // Adicione aqui sua mensagem
$mensagem .= "--$boundary" . PHP_EOL;

$mensagem .= "Content-Type: ". $fileType ."; name=\"". $fileName . "\"" . PHP_EOL;
$mensagem .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . PHP_EOL;
$mensagem .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"". $fileName . "\"" . PHP_EOL;
$mensagem .= "$anexo" . PHP_EOL;
$mensagem .= "--$boundary" . PHP_EOL;

$envio = mail("eduardo@fmaconsulting.com.br", $assunto, $mensagem, $headers);
```

Alguém tem um exemplo de simples, pra enviar email com anexo!

Comment: O que a hospedagem alegou? sobre o usar o phpmailer? outra opção seria o [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). Gerar esse cabeçalho de anexo na mão é bastante trabalhoso e sujeito a erros.

Comment: Sempre uso o PHPMAILER, mas por algum motivo não funcionou. Ao entrar em contato com o suporte da hospedagem, me disseram que o PHPMAILER não funciona, tinha que ser a função email()

Comment: Qual o servidor de hospedagem? Verifique na documentação do servidor, que eles devem ter alguma informação técnica sobre as regras de saída. Como por exemplo na locaweb, entram alguns cabeçalhos obrigatórios.
http://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/PHP_Mail_-_Como_enviar_e-mails_utilizando_a_fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_Mail_nativa_do_PHP

Comment: Já falei com eles, o retorno que tive, foi que não pode ser PHPMAILER, POIS É BLOQUEADO, tem que ser via função mail()

Comment: Parece que é locaweb, pesquisei pelo domínio fmaconsulting.com.br: https://registro.br/cgi-bin/whois/#lresp
Lembrando que para enviar email pela função mail deles, tem que ser do mesmo domínio o email que envia, e tem algumas regras para envio. Dá uma lida no wiki locaweb.

Comment: Esse emal é meu de teste, que é mesmo da locaWeb, com ele funciona quando texto no servidor, mas o serviço de email do cliente não funciona quando coloco o email dele, quando coloco as informações na estrutura ja existente, do PHPMAILER. Preciso só de um exemplo com a função emal() que envie anexo... Somente isso, pois ja procurei na net, e a maioria esta com erro

Answer (score 0):

Não obtive a resposta que queria, mas consegui o resultado que esperava. Entrei em contato novamente com redeHost, me passaram outro e smtpexc01.redehost.com.br resolveu meu problema.