# Enviar email com PHP

Tags: php, email

Galera, alguém meda um passo a passo de como eu faço em PHP para enviar emails, PHPMailer ou mail(), tanto faz, enviando o email é que importa, eu já tentei de tudo e não to conseguindo de jeito nenhum.

Aqui o código que to usando:

```
if (isset($_POST["recovery_pass"]))
{
  if (filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
  {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
  }
  else
  {
    echo "email is not valid";
        exit;
    }

  // Check to see if a user exists with this e-mail
    $query = $conexao->prepare('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :email');
    $query->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $query->execute();
    $userExists = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $conexao = null;

    if ($userExists["email"])
    {
        // Create a unique salt. This will never leave PHP unencrypted.
        $salt = "498#2D83B631%3800EBD!801600D*7E3CC13";

        // Create the unique user password reset key
        $password = hash('sha512', $salt.$userExists["email"]);

        // Create a url which we will direct them to reset their password
        $pwrurl = "$linkSite/recovery_pass/$password";

        require ("phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
        // Inicia a classe PHPMailer
        $mail = new PHPMailer;

        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'curruwilla@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = '';                           // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 587;

        // Define o remetente
        // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
        $mail->setFrom = ('curruwilla@gmail.com'); // Seu e-mail

        // Define os destinatário(s)
        // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
        $mail->AddAddress($email);

        $mail->IsHTML(true); // Define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML
        //$mail->CharSet = 'iso-8859-1'; // Charset da mensagem (opcional)
        $mail->Subject = "Recuperação de senha"; // Assunto da mensagem
        $mail->Body = "Este é o corpo da mensagem de teste, em ".$pwrurl." <b>HTML</b>!  :)";
        $mail->AltBody = "Este é o corpo da mensagem de teste, em Texto Plano! \r\n :)";

        // Envia o e-mail
        $enviado = $mail->Send();

        // Limpa os destinatários e os anexos
        $mail->ClearAllRecipients();

        // Exibe uma mensagem de resultado
        if ($enviado) {
            echo "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
        } else {
            echo "Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.";
            echo "<b>Informações do erro:</b> " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
        }
        else
        echo "No user with that e-mail address exists.";
        }
?>

<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">

<fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" maxlength="70" size="70" required>
</fieldset>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="recovery_pass" value="Recovery">
```

Comment: [Dificuldades no Envio de E-mail usando PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/67012/91)

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=email+php+is%3Aquestion

Comment: @WilliamAlvares olhando seu código, não tem nada de errado com ele. Bate com o exemplo do próprio phpmailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps resta saber o que aparece em  $mail->ErrorInfo quando você tenta enviar. Também tem que ver se você habilitou usar SMTP no seu gmail.

Comment: Amigo ativa o Debug para facilitar a identificação do problema. $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // enables SMTP debug information (for testing) // 1 = errors and messages // 2 = messages only

Comment: @RafaelMenaBarreto Apareceu isso tudo: 2016-01-22 19:13:58 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0) 2016-01-22 19:13:58 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.Informações do erro: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: @WilliamAlvares a mensagem de erro aponta pra uma falha na sua rede. O computador onde roda esse código está com internet, DNS funcionando? Tem algum bloqueio de porta ou firewall?

Comment: @RafaelMenaBarreto Eles tão mexendo eu acho, adicionado SSL, interfere ?? Acho que vou dar um tempo, até o SSL estar adicionado e adicionado o IP Dedicado..

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como enviar e-mail do localhost usando a função mail do PHP?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40858/como-enviar-e-mail-do-localhost-usando-a-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-mail-do-php)

Comment: William Alvares, Quando for fazer uma pergunta/dúvidas procure dar mais detalhes significativos para que possamos entender o seu problema e poder te ajudar a resolver, Procure sempre informar: código usado, mensagem erro, objetivo, estrutura/local onde está tentando. Assim fica mais fácil de você receber uma solução e evitar de ter a sua pergunta fechada. Fica a Dica aí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui, segue abaixo o código funcionando!

```
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

        $mail = new PHPMailer;

        //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;

        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.live.com';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = 'meuemailoutlook';
        $mail->Password = 'secret';
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Port = 587;

        $mail->setFrom('meuemailoutlook', '5tars');
        $mail->addAddress($email);

        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->CharSet = 'iso-8859-1';

        $mail->Subject = 'Recuperação de senha';
        $mail->Body    = 'Este é o corpo da mensagem de teste, em '.$pwrurl.' <b>HTML</b>!  :)';
        $mail->AltBody = 'Este é o corpo da mensagem de teste, em Texto Plano! \r\n :)';

        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo 'Message could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo 'Message has been sent';
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema parece ser porque você não configurou o php.ini.
procure no arquivo por

`[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25`

Em `SMTP =` você indica o servidor SMTP que vai utilizar para enviar a mensagem.

Este link pode ajudar :http://www.criarweb.com/faq/configurar-php-ini-smtp.html

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/53085)

Comment: Sorry Ricardo, sou novo aqui.