# Enviar email PHP+CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Pessoas, fiz vários exemplos, sendo eles de livros ou da internet e todos retornam o seguinte mensagem quando executo a função para enviar o email:

**Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()**

Poderiam por favor explicar o que é esse SMTP? E o que eu deveria fazer para funcionar?

Obrigado.

Comment: [Dificuldades no Envio de E-mail usando PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/67017/91)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (abreviado SMTP. Traduzido do inglês, significa "Protocolo de transferência de correio simples") é o protocolo padrão para envio de e-mails através da Internet.

Você pode postar trecho do seu código para que possamos analizar melhor seu problema?

Mas responda algumas perguntas: Você quer enviar e-mail no seu localhost? ou já possui um servidor web configurado ?

Comment: Olá, já consegui resolver, agradeço a sua ajuda.