# É possível enviar um email pelo comando "sendmail" de uma máquina local?

Tags: linux, sendmail

Eu aprendi a pouco tempo a usar meu servidor da Amazon para enviar emails com o comando `sendmail`. Funciona tudo perfeitamente.

Eu queria saber se tinha como fazer a mesma coisa através da minha máquina local. Porque, teoricamente, o servidor também é uma máquina. Se ele pode enviar com `sendmail`, eu também poderia através da minha máquina, para fazer testes, por exemplo?

Comment: Está a usar Linux ?

Comment: @JorgeCosta sim, eu coloquei na tag da pergunta.

Comment: Desculpe não tinha verificado

Comment: @JorgeCosta  Ubuntu 16, para facilitar mais ainda :p

Answer (score 1):

Bastaria configurar um SMTP valido no `sendmail.ini`, como expliquei em:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/67017/3635

algo como (exemplo com Gmail):

```
[sendmail]
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
default_domain=gmail.com

auth_username=[seuemail]@gmail.com
auth_password=[suasenha]
```

Creio que se instalou "global" pode usar o comando:

```
$ sudo sendmailconfig
```

---

Nota para localizar o arquivo `sendmail.ini` pode experimentar o comando:

```
$ find -iname "sendmail.ini"
```